# Finding the maximum integer in an array using binary search tree, return giving garbage value

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to get the maximum value from a binary search tree. The problem is that the "getmax" function is returning a garbage value to "max". What am I doing wrong here? If you see any error please let me know.

I haven't included the insert function here.
Edit: here's the entire program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct mynode_tag
{
  int index;
  struct mynode_tag *right;
  struct mynode_tag *left;
} mynode;

void insert(mynode **root, int index)
{

  mynode *tmp;

  if (*root == NULL)
    {
      tmp = malloc(sizeof(mynode));
      if (tmp == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory\n");
      return;
    }
      tmp->index = index;
      *root = tmp;
     }

  else
    {
       if (index> (*root)->index)
    {
       insert(&(*root)->right, index);
    }

      else
        {
      insert(&(*root)->left,index);
    }
    }
}


int getmax(mynode * root)
{

if (root->right !=NULL)
  {getmax(root->right);}

if (root->right == NULL)
  { printf("Root-index inside function %d\n", root->index); //gives the right value
    return (root->index);}

}

int main (int argc, char * v[])
{
int index[6] = {0, 2, 9, 10, 3, 7};

int i;
int max;

mynode *root = NULL;

for (i=0; i<6; i++)
  {
   insert(&root, index[i]);
  }

max = getmax(root);

printf("The largest number in the array is %d\n",a); 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I need you to show the insert function to answer precisely.  However, I believe that the problem is that you are dropping the returned value in recursive call to getmax.
Try:

```
if (root->right !=NULL)
{
     return ( getmax(root->right) );
}
```